# How to update configuration files in Docker-compose volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a `docker-compose` setup, and when I want to update files in my image I create a new docker image. Though the problem is; the file I'm editing is located in the persistent volume, meaning the Docker image itself will get the changes, but since I'm not deleting docker-compose volumes the volume will be used by the new image, hence the old file will be used by new image.

Running `docker-compose down -v` is not an options because I want to keep other existing files in the volume (logs etc.).

I want to know if it possible to do this without too much hacks, since I'm looking to automate this.

Example *docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  myService:
    image: myImage
    container_name: myContainer
    volumes:
      - data_volume:/var/data

volumes:
  data_volume
```

**NOTE:** The process of doing change in my case:

1. `docker-compose down`
2. `docker build -t myImage:t1 .`
3. `docker compose up -d`

Comment: Can you restructure your application to store the configuration and data (and code and logs) in different directories?  Then you could bind-mount a directory of configuration files over `/etc/myapp` while you have a named volume holding opaque data mounted on `/var/data`.

Comment: How can I make sure that data is not dupliated, meaning: Let's say I have 10 files and 1 directory in the same directory `/var/data`, I can easily mount a volume to that one directory in the `data_volume:/var/data/dirX`, but how do I make sure to exclude `/var/data/dirX`  when I'm gonna bind/mount the rest of files or directories in `/var/data`? Is it possible to bind/mount the same directories twice ?

Comment: @DavidMaze, but then again wouldn't this be problematic when coverting from 1 volume to 2 , and this could cause issues when taking backup from two different volumes?

Answer (score 0):

You could start a container, mount the volume and execute a command to delete single files. Something like

```
docker run -d --rm -v data_volume:/var/data myImage rm /var/data/[file to delete]
```

Comment: This could solve the problem, but it's too short term and wouldn't scale the way I see it.